# Swift - Run code when user dismiss UIReferenceLibraryViewController

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

I need to run a piece of code when user dissmisses the UIReferenceLibraryViewController. But my code that I previously coded isn't working on iOS 13.

Here is the code I wrote for iOS 12:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  if UIReferenceLibraryViewController.dictionaryHasDefinition(forTerm: word) {
    let ref: UIReferenceLibraryViewController = 
      UIReferenceLibraryViewController(term: word)
      ref.reactive
      .trigger(for: #selector(onboardNav.viewDidDisappear(_:)))
      .observe { _ in self.handleModalDismissed() }

      self.present(ref, animated: false, completion: nil)
   }
}

func handleModalDismissed() { // I need to run this function when user presses "Back" button
    self.showAlert(error: false, word: "")
}
```

Comment: [UIReferenceLibraryViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uireferencelibraryviewcontroller) doesn't have property `reactive` - is this property comes from some third party library?

Comment: I don't know, I read this in here: https://medium.com/@augusteo/reactive-way-to-handle-dismissing-modal-view-controller-81af09f886f6

Comment: Yea, you are right! Just realized that it is used in ReactiveCocoa... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found an answer! You need to subclass a `UIReferenceLibraryViewController`, and override `viewWillDisappear`. Like so:

```
class ReferenceLibraryViewControllerWithDismiss: UIReferenceLibraryViewController {
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        // your code
    }

}
```

And then present `ReferenceLibraryViewControllerWithDismiss`:

```
let vc = ReferenceLibraryViewControllerWithDismiss()
self.present(vc, animated: true)
```

Happy coding!